# What is gradient descent.does gradient descent can give better result than sklearn linear regression algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why we use gradient descent because sklearn can automatically find best fit line for our data.what is the purpose of gradient descent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html

if you want to use Gradient Descent approach, you should consider using SDRClassifier in SKlearn because SKlearn gives two Approaches to using Linear Regression. The first is LinearRegression class and is using  ***Ordinary Least Squares solver from scipy***
the other one is SDRClassifier class which is an Implementation of the Gradient Descent Algorithm. So to answer your Question if you are using SDRClassifier in SKlearn then you are using an Implementation of Gradient Descent Algorithm behind the Scene.

Comment: Basilisk which is best linear regression model or sdrclassifier.which giver you better result.

Comment: @ManinderSingh: I think it depends sometimes but generally, linear regression with Gradient Descent is better than Ordinary least squares (OLS). The idea is, if the task is simple and can be directly solved using OLS, then using OLS is better but if the task is more complex then using Gradient descent is better because it is an iterative process to find the best solution for a regression problem.

Comment: @ManinderSingh OLS is not an iterative process, it uses multivariate calculus to solve an equation, which is inefficient if you have a big dataset and will fail if there is mathematically no solution for the probelm, in contrast gradient descent is the way to go if you have a big dataset (because it is an iterative process to search for a solution) and even if there is mathematically no solution for the probelm, then it will search for a local minimum which you can consider as the best way to approximate a solution for the regression problem

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia itself

> Gradient descent is a first-order iterative optimization algorithm for
>   finding the minimum of a function. To find a local minimum of a
>   function using gradient descent, one takes steps proportional to the
>   negative of the gradient (or approximate gradient) of the function at
>   the current point.

Gradient descent is just another approach used for converging, maximizing likelihood. There are other alternatives with their limitations.

The LinearRegression model in sklearn is just a fancy wrapper of the least squares solver (scipy.linalg.lstsq) built into scipy.

Answer (score 0):

A gradient descent isn't much more than just following the slope locally.

[image]

If you're using a gradient descent, you're essentially taking into account how much has the value of the function you're trying to minimize changed as a function of one or more parameters. You can use that information to make a better guess as to what parameters values is likely to work best to minimize the function at the next step.

The [image here](https://hackernoon.com/gradient-descent-aynk-7cbe95a778da) is in 2D (so you would only have 2 parameters determining the value of your function to minimize). However it still remains conceptually the same (just with harder maths behind the scenes) with as many parameters as you want to use.

So a gradient descent, essentially, means taking your bicycle and letting the local slope lead you to the nearest local minimum.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: gradient descent can get a solution for many models - from Logistic Regression to neural networks, called Multi-Layer Perceptrons in SKlearn (MLP).

If you are solving only for a simple linear model, then using gradient descent (like in Basilisk's answer) really has some minor benefits at the cost of performance (more flexible, but more slow). I used it when I needed more flexibility.

Besides the point, note that this question is not about programming, it is about machine learning, and should go to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) instead of Stack Overflow - though you might also want to start with the fundamentals (think about this - what do we mean by "best fit line"?).